# Regex search in JQ

Tags: regex, jq

I am looking for a regular expression in my `jq` query (using. It's a pretty simple one, I want to match entries starting with a number `\d` (or `[0-9]`) and ending in `linux`. What I've tried so far:

```
versions=`echo $allversions| jq '.tags[] | select(startswith("\d")) | select(endswith("linux"))'`
```

but I don't think `startwith` doesn't support regular expression. I'm reading that `match` supports regular expression, but I cannot find proper documentation or examples about it. A simple `'jq '.tags[]| match("\d.*linux")'` doesn't work and gives a syntax error message:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `"\d*linux"'
```

How can I accomplish this? Or should I combine `jq` with `sed` instead?

FYI:

```
$ jq --version
jq-1.6
```

Comment: BTW, `echo $allversions` is itself buggy. See [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` prints something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else). Always, _always_ quote your expansions: `echo "$allversions"` -- see what happens if your JSON contains a string with a `*` surrounded by whitespace (and you're using a POSIX-compliant shell, notably _not_ zsh) otherwise.

Comment: ...that is to say, `json='{"key": "this is * a string"}'; echo $json` can have a list of files in the current directory injected into your string. (Not the only way unquoted expansions can corrupt a string, but one of the more dramatic ones).

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found how to do it!

```
jq -r '.tags[] | select(test("^[0-9].*linux"))'
```

Comment: You want a `$` on the end to be equivalent to `endswith`. Right now this will succeed if `linux` is anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments to regex functions must be JSON strings, so any regex backslash must be escaped.  Thus, instead of `match("\d.*linux")`
you'd write:

`match("\\d.*linux")`